# Syntax highlighting in fmt and GoLand

Tags: go, syntax-highlighting, goland

How does the GoLand IDE (JetBrains) highlight the formatting verbs in the `fmt` package from the Go standard library?

An image to clarify my question:

[image: Highlight example]

If I write a function that takes a format string and multiple arguments, the format string is not highlighted:

[image: No Highlight example]

Where does this highlighting come from? I was not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently, as of 2019.3 release, supported by the IDE.

Vote/watch [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5841) to receive updates when it will be implemented.